# Arm64 - Absolute branching generating exception

Tags: assembly, arm64, osdev, bare-metal

Jumping to a C function using its absolute address (0x80904) in 64arm with BLR fails:

```
LDR x3, =0x80904 
SUB x0, x3, x19
BL print_x0 // Prints something to uart, i.e, x0 == x19

BLR x19  // Fails!
```

The address is good: `BLR x3` works.

x19 value is not changing after `print_x0`. I tested it.

Why is branching generating this exception?

Thank you!

Comment: Is that code address in executable memory, according to page tables or any other memory-protection settings?

Comment: Also is `sp` valid? No idea if that would cause the same exception.

Comment: If the lowest 6 bits of `esr_el1` can be trusted, then according to the manual this would be an "Address size fault, level 0 of translation or translation table base register", suggesting your page tables map to a physical address out of range... otherwise I agree with @Jester: makie sure that `sp` is valid, and additionally check if you have SP alignment checks enabled (and if so, make sure SP is actually 16-byte aligned).

Comment: Thanks for the quick feedback! I believe my MMU is disabled, so I would expect no memory to be protected (does that make sense?). Also, I'm using a Raspberry PI with 4GB of memory, so I suppose 80904 isn't out of range. The weird thing is, I can call another function immediately before my problematic branch using "bl anotherFunc" without problems. That led me to think the stack is not the issue. Anyway, you might have noticed that I'm a amateur in bare metal programming, so maybe nothing I say makes sense... :-)

Comment: Also, I'm able to execute the function using C, so I assume it is not a memory-protection issue, but, again, I might be mistaken.

Comment: Any chance that `anotherFunc` screwed up the stack?  Anyway, it seems like it would be useful to have a register dump at the site of the `blr x19`, if you have a way to produce one.

Comment: I've already tried commenting anotherFun, but the error is still there. Which register would you like to see the values? I don't have JTAG or anything like this but I can manually try to print something to the UART. There is no emulator for the PI 4, so I can't use QEMU or anything similar either.

Comment: I updated my question with some (hopefully) useful information.

Comment: If `BL function` worked, my guess is that some kind of runtime relocation or other fixup means that `80904` isn't the true runtime address of the function.  (I assume `80904` is from disassembly of the kernel image; possibly linked for an address other than where it was actually loaded?)  Since you did have that value in `x19`, or at least the fault handler showed that address, probably `x19` is getting a value from the right place (and it's not a matter of scribbling over your pointer in memory before loading x19 or something).

Comment: `bl` is I think a *relative* branch in machine code, not actually absolute, so it can be used between functions in a position-independent kernel image.  i.e. loading your kernel at a different address than it was linked for won't break it, but will break things like `static funcptr p = function;` that actually do store an absolute address as data.

Comment: Thanks, again for your reply. When I print ```&function``` before I successfully call ```function``` I also get 80904. Similarly, printing x0 after ```ldr x0, =function``` from C gives me 80904. That leads me to think the address is the good one, but I might be mistaken.

Comment: That wouldn't really help - those would both give the "intended" address of `function` rather than where you actually end up jumping to.  What if you dump a few words from the absolute address `0x80904` and see if they match the machine code of the function?

Comment: As for a register dump, `x19` and `sp` would be useful, and perhaps `pc` to see if it matches the address where the calling code is supposed to be.  `adr x0, .` will get `pc` into a register for you, at least in GNU as.

Comment: I get the same exception when trying to read that address in order to dump: ```ldr     x0, [x2]``` results in the error, where x2 = 0x80904

Comment: My PC is 0x81E0C a few instructions behind my  ```BLR x19```

Comment: And where does `objdump` show that your `BLR x19` is supposed to be?  Another idea is to dump the value of `pc` from within `process` and see what it shows when you call it via `BL`.

Comment: objdump says it is at 80904. I'll try to put some inline assembly to attempt getting pc's value when inside the function.

Comment: I tried to put this inside my function 
```int (*functionPtr)() = 0x80904; (functionPtr)();```
expecting to get an error and figure out the PC address through the exception... it turns out I just entered a "infinite recursion". i.e., it looks like it worked to call the same address from C...

Comment: `printf("%p\n", __builtin_return_address(0));` may be useful; you can compare a return address against the call site in objdump output.  (Or yeah, just use `asm` to copy `pc` to an `"=r"` output.)  Any other way of asking for an absolute address could be using some other mechanism (like a GOT entry if you compile with `-fPIC`) which may be broken due to bugs or mistaken assumptions made by code about how it will be loaded.  AArch64 has efficient PC-relative address generation so you'd *expect* that `&function` would be generated in a PC-relative way, but it might not be esp. without `-fPIE`.

Comment: Ok, I managed to get it working... but I don't really understand what the problem was. I will put an answer (but won't make it as the good answer, with what I had to do to make it work, feel free to jump in if you like)

Comment: I really appreciate all of your help! Thank you all so much!

Comment: Ignore earlier comments about `x19` being call-clobbered - it's callee-saved, so it should be preserved across C function calls.  Of course that means that if your code is called *by* C code, you have to arrange that it is saved and restored - which won't be possible if you're expecting the function you call to return directly to the original C caller.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, thank you all for your help! I got it to work. That said, I don't really understand what the problem was.

The function below created a structure containing the address to the function I call (see `fn`). This address was later loaded into x19 before I would attempt `BLR x19`.

```
struct task_struct * copy_process(unsigned long fn)
{
    struct task_struct *p;
    p = (struct task_struct *)get_free_page();

    char buff[] = "0000000000000000";
    parse_int((unsigned long)fn, buff, 16);
    uart_send_string("fn: ");
    uart_send_string(buff);
    uart_send_string("\n");

    // Configure the task struct
    p->cpu_context.x19 = fn;
    return p;
}
```

It suffices to comment out `parse_int((unsigned long)fn, buff, 16);` and everything works as expected.

Here is what `parse_int` looks like:

```
void parse_int(u64 number, char* str, int base) {
    if(base > 36)
        return;

    int length = 0;
    while (str[length] != '\0') {
        str[length] = '0';
        length++;
    }

    char remainder;
    while(number >= 0 && length >= 0) {
        length--;
        remainder = (number % base);
        if(remainder > 9) {
            remainder -= 10;
            str[length] = 'A' + remainder;    
        } else {
            str[length] = '0' + remainder;
        }
        number /= base;
    }
}
```

I guess somehow memory was getting corrupted in this call, I can't see how, though.

If you know the reason, feel free to jump in with an answer to the original problem and I'll mark it as the good one. I will also delete this answer of mine, as this is probably not helpful for someone with the same problem.

Thanks

Comment: When `length` gets to 0 in your second loop, you will decrement it again and access `str[-1]` which is bad.

Comment: And `number` is unsigned so `number >= 0` is always true.  Thus you will get down to `length == 0` regardless of the input.

Comment: Shame on me! I spent days trying to figure out what was wrong.. it turned out I had just committed these silly logic mistakes. It all works after fixing the while condition.

I guess I'm too used to programming in a high-level language that accuses when I do things like going beyond the boundaries. In my defense, I probably coded that late night after work :-)

Comment: You do get a warning for the `number >= 0` bug if you enable `-Wextra`.

Comment: Thanks I didn't know about this option. I just had -Wall, which I thought would cover every possible warning.

Comment: `parse_int` is mis-named - it *formats* an int as a string.  "parsing" implies reading text, not creating it.  And BTW, for performance you probably want to special-case a couple common bases like 10 and 16, so the compiler will generate special-case loops that divide by those specific constants (with a shift for 16, or a multiplicative inverse for 10) instead of using a slow generic udiv instruction. See glibc's example of this: https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/895ef79e04a953cac1493863bcae29ad85657ee1/stdio-common/_itoa.c#L163. (Also note returning a first-digit ptr instead of 0 padding)

Comment: I appreciate the feedback. This function is kind of a draft I used just for debugging, so performance isn't a big issue there, but I'll keep that in mind. And yes, you are right about the name being wrong. Thanks!